# How to center Textview inside Listview using RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, arrays

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_haltestellen, R.id.tvHaltestellen, HaltestellenListe);
lvH.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

this is how the stuff is set and .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHaltestellen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    />
```

I get the StringArray from a database.
so how can center the tv inside the listview? realy bad thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this one: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHaltestellen"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what do you want to do, but if you want to center the `TextView` inside the `RelativeLayout` then remove

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

from TV and try adding something like `android:layout_centarInParent="true"`, and in the relative layout change `match_parent` to `wrap_contents`

Comment: the textview is in listview. i want the textview to be in center of the listview

Answer (score 0):

You could anchor the `TextView` to the top and bottom of the `ListView` (and optionally left and right too, depending on the desired effect). That will make the `TextView` equally tall (and optionally wide), so use a center gravity to position the text in the middle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you're planning to add a background colour to the `TextView`, you'll need to wrap it inside another transparent container (e.g. a `FrameLayout`), to avoid the colour from obscuring what's displayed in the list. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lvHaltestellen"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lvHaltestellen" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHaltestellen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively, if you decide to make the `ListView` fill up the whole height of the `RelativeLayout`, you don't need to anchor the `TextView` to the list anymore. As already pointed out by @user1796624, you can then just center the `TextView`.

As per your earlier comment on someone else's answer:

> the textview is shown inside the listview.

I understand what you're trying to say here, but please do realize that the `TextView` does *not* sit inside the `ListView`, but rather floats on top of it.